# BGP announcements?

Tags: networking, bgp

Can anyone explain how announcing in BGP works? I understand BGP finds the shortest/lowest-cost path to a destination network, but I also read somewhere that it announces these paths. Is that true, and how exactly does it announce a route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BGP is  Exterior Gateway Protocol and it is used in the network Borders between Autonomous systems , announcing network work like this example :
for example we have 3 Autonomous systems A,B
A have those tow networks 1.1.1.0/24 and 2.2.2.0/24
B have those tow network  3.3.3.0/24 and 4.4.4.0/24
so Edge router in A directly connected to Edge router in B and running BGP , every router announce (or advertise) which internal networks it have ( or want to publish) so now A routers know that there is 3.3.3.0/24 and 4.4.4.0/24 networks and they are reachable via  Edge router of B and same with  B networks